# Terminal based IDE

Tags: java, linux, ssh, ide, terminal

I'm looking for a IDE that supports java and is based over terminal. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and it doesn't have any gui installed and I'd prefer to keep it that way. However, I'd also like to code on it and connect to it from other computers using SSH to code on there to provide a lightweight and fast IDE.

It has to be able to edit, compile, and test Java on the spot, and more languages if possible.

It would be nice if it had support for multiple projects and had a collapsible project browser, like in netbeans and most IDE's.

Does anyone know anything that meets the requirements?

I'd love something like http://www.spartacusrex.com/terminalide-1280x800.jpg however thats only for android.

Answer (score 3):

[emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) is the only example I can think of. You might be able to get along with vim, but there will be a lot of `ESC :!` shell calls.